# Splitting 4 lights on one switch into 2 lights each on own switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

Currently have 1 switch that controls 4 lights (2 recessed lights on our front porch and 2 lights next to the garage). I want to put the 2 garage lights on their own switch. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you turn off the circuit, open up the existing switch box and, without disconnecting any wires, take pictures showing all the cables/wires and how they connect to the existing switch?

Comment: Adding to that comment - it will depend on your existing wiring.  You may be lucky and have separate feeds to the garage lights and porch lights right in your switch box (in which case you can just add a switch and connect one of them to it).  Or your existing switch may feed just a single line out to all of the lights, in which case you will need to run additional electrical cables (or wires, if in conduit) to either garage or porch such that they are separate from the other.

Comment: This is going to need a _lot_ more info it we're going to have the slightest chance of helping you. _Can_ you do it? Sure! _How_? based on what you've given us, we don't have any more of a clue than you do.